# SQL Server - Is there a way to query the specific Size and Space available settings for each Database, including system databases on an instance?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to query the two default database properties as seen in the picture below for all databases on an instance, including system databases.

I've used various scripts such as the following, but I'm not sure exactly where data for those two fields are stored.

```
SELECT 
      database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID() -- for current db 
GROUP BY database_id
```

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: HI @John M, thanks for the post!  The answer returns no results for me on multiple servers and a divide by zero error on another server.  I appreciate the link though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the properties of the model database - everything else being equal a new database is created using the model database as a template.
If you want to change the default size, resize your model database - job done.
Note however if the database creation script supplies a specific value that will take precedence.

re-read the question including your title and I think you want the results of running

```
exec sp_helpdb
```

or try if you want to see the space available

```
exec sp_msforeachdb "use [?]; exec sp_spaceused"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stephen Morris.  I think all the DB's have a custom size.

Comment: The 'exec sp_spaceused' got me what I was after.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the DatabaseSizeSP stored procedure - it will show file sizes and space used information for each database

It can be found here:

https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools

Deploy to any database and run it

[image: DatabaseSizeSP]

Comment: Thanks @Aleksey, this is a great script.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Ah, I had misread the question as wanting to know the free space the DBs had to expand into on the storage system, not the free space amongst that already allocated, so this answer does not exactly cover the question.*</sub>

---

I doubt in a truly reliable manner. You would have to get the figures per file not per DB as each file making up the database could be on a different volume, and you need to account for the fact that some files from multiple DBs could be on the same volume. Also if you are using network attached storage any space available figure could be unreliable both because the volume size could be dynamic and because there are other uses applying pressure on available space at any given time.

I assume the figure presented in SSMS is coming from it looking at the filesystem instead of being read from data held in system tables/views.

Comment: Thanks @David Spillett.  I appreciate your answer.  For my particular purpose, I'm more interested in getting the numbers as they are set in the properties, rather than the actual current sizes of the DB.  Exec sp_spaceused got me the numbers I was after.  Thanks again for taking the time to help me, this has been helpfu.